# How to replace characters conditionally in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel spreadsheets I need to replace one comma with one space in strings where the comma is in 5th position, like this:

```
1390,0775
```

However, when the comma is not in the 5th position, like this

```
1Za-K-1,5
```

... nothing should happen

Is there a way to accomplish this with a formula in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(MID(A1,5,1)=",",REPLACE(A1,5,1," "),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to translate this into my Swedish Excel version: =OM(EXTEXT(B2;5;1)=",";ERSÄTT(B2;5;1;" ");B2). You saved me a lot of work!